# check session in another controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

After the user logs in, I set the variable `is_logged_in=true`, but in some other controller how can I check `is_logged_in` is true in codeigniter?
Here is my login code:

```
public login_con extends CI_Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        is_logged_in=true;
    }
}
```

I want to check this `is_logged_in` in another controller so how can i write code for that?

Comment: Perhaps put it in the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session is best solution for this. You can read codeignitor [session](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

```
// set value in session 
$this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in', true);
```

To get in other controller

```
$is_logged_in  = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
```

Please also make sure you have loaded session library.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing autoload `applications/config/autoload.php`, to add session library

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

This will include session on every page.

Now your controller file

**controller1**

```
    public login_con extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function login()
        {
           //here you set session like that
           $data['is_logged_in'] = TRUE;
           $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        }
    }
```

Here you get your `is_logged_in` session on other controller

**controller2**

```
public your_con extends CI_Controller
        {
            public function your_function()
            {
               //here you get session like that
              if($this->session->userdata("is_logged_in"))
                {
                  // your code here
                 }
            }
        }
```

Comment: #saty thx for this..and one more clarification how can i use base controller  for this functionality?..

Comment: @CroosPraveen what do you mean by base controller??

Comment: You have to create one common controller inside like application/core/MY_Controller.php. This is the base controller. This should extends CI_Controller and your controller file should be extend MY_Controller.php. So by using this method you can define common variables in MY_Controller.php and access those variables in sub controllers without using session.